# Matplotlib LaTeX text rendering exclusively for axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using Matplotlib, how can I apply LaTeX text rendering *exclusively* for axis labels, while tick labels and other texts are not affected and rendered as usual? Or, is there a way to use different font families for axis and tick labels?

Edit:

Thanks to commenters, I found following code works

```py
# code A
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(5))
ax.set_xlabel('$x$', usetex=True)
plt.show()
```

to produce a figure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcWbk.png) which is the one desired. But I have a trouble with following code that affects the tick rendering too as in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjptp.png).

```py
# code B
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'text.usetex': True, })
_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(5))
ax.set_xlabel('$x$', usetex=True)
plt.show()
```

I want to configure my [custom style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-style-sheets) such that it produces results like the code A's. But I can't find an option that applies the LaTeX rendering exclusively for axis labels (an option `text.usetex: True` works identically to the code B).

Comment: See This:[https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html?highlight=latex](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html?highlight=latex)

Comment: `ax.set_xlabel('My Label', usetex=True)` should work.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks! That works, but I'm looking for a way to configure my MPL style sheet to make such rendering style default.

Comment: The style sheet cannot be infinitely flexible.